# Code Organization in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Hello everyone I have a question:
I would like to implement restkit but I have no idea how to set up the structure.
Should I put everything in a class singleton

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

    + (instancetype) sharedmanager;

    - (void) fetchUsersWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *users, NSError *error))completionHandler;

    - (void) fetchIssuesWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *issues, NSError    *error))completionHandler;

    - (void) authenticationWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL *success, NSError *error))completionHandler;

    - (BOOL) isAuthenticated;

@end
```

or grouped by class without using a singleton class and create RKObjectManager in the superclass

```
@interface Manager : NSObject

    @property(nonatomic, strong) RKObjectManager *manager;

@end


@interface User : Manager

    - (void) fetchUsersWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *users, NSError *error))completionHandler;

@end

@interface Issues : Manager

   - (void) fetchIssuesWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *issues, NSError *error))completionHandler;

@end

@interface authentication : Manager

   - (void) authenticationWithHandlerCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL *success, NSError *error))completionHandler;

   - (BOOL) isAuthenticated;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much personal preference and would be driven by how big you expect the interface to be.

Another option is to have a singleton which defines the most common functionality and uses categories in appropriately names files to add lesser used or more specific functionality. The benefit here is that you don't waste resources by instantiating multiple object managers and duplicating that common setup and mapping code.

Comment: the interface is large enough. 
The third option that I have proposed is very attractive. I had not thought of that.

Comment: Follow your option, advise me where to put the code mapping in the categories or in the singleton

Comment: I would use categories, .h to import into the files which use and .m to implement those mappings.